# Preventing vim script from being applied to itself

Tags: vim, macros

I have a vim script with substitutions:

```
:%s/|I\(cc\|ee\|CC\|EE\)|/|$I_{\1}$|/
:%s/|UOmax\([+-]\)|/|$U_{Omax\1}$|/
:%s/|KcmR|/|$K_{cmR}$|/
:%s/|KsvR|/|$K_{svR}$|/
:%s/Uoffset/$U_{offset}$/
..............
```

Sometimes I forget that this script is currently edited, so I execute `so ~/.vim/macros/script.vim` and it is modifying itself. How to make script know that it is currently edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check that `expand('%:p') != expand('<sfile>:p')` before continuing.

Honestly, I'm not sure I'd bother with that as `u`ndo will quickly fix the issue, and moreover as I often open many buffers, I'm likely make the mistake on any buffer.

BTW, another approach would be to define a `tex` ftplugin, where you'd define a fucntion that does the substitutions, and a buffer-local mapping that executes the function on the current buffer. This way, you won't have the possibility to run the substitution on buffers that are not LaTeX ones.

Comment: Thanks. I'm so inattentive that I save files and exit vim before undoing :)

Comment: Ah... That's the secret then: I never leave vim.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [vim-quickrun](https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun) and type `<leader>r`. vim-quickrun run the script from buffer instead of file if it's modified.